Keyboard on ubuntu 22.04 on xorg doesn't work with some applications
I have a new installation of ubuntu 22.04
If I log into Wayland everything works fine.
Logging into 'Ubuntu on xorg' my keyboard works, EXCEPT on some applications (doesn't work on firefox or chrome, or the default pdf document viewer). Works ok with the Falkon webbrowser.
So if I try and type anywhere on firefox, nothing happens. But I can copy and paste text with the mouse.
Any advice appreciated
Michael
